# how to wire a timer without negative using ground

Tags: timer, wiring

I have a switch i would like to replace with a timer like this

http://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx3DCN3HLSARWFS/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B004SOZHXY

i only have a positive wire in my switch box,

could i use the (ground) box as a negative?

is it safe?

EDIT: i linked the wrong model above

would this do any better?

[http://www.amazon.com/Honeywell-RPLS530A-7-Day-Programmable-Switch/dp/B004SOZHR0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SOZHR0)

Comment: You cannot use ground as neutral without violating code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think it's worse than you think - it sounds like he wants to use the *electrical box* that holds the switch as neutral! But they do make switches that can be placed in-line (often labeled 3-way)

Answer (score 1):

No.  The device you have requires a grounded (neutral) conductor to be connected to function.  There's no other way to hook it up.

I believe Honeywell offers timers that don't require a grounded (neutral) connection. You might want to purchase one of those instead.

Comment: Yeah -- he needs an RPLS530 or RPLS540, not the RPLS730 he is trying to buy *sigh*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel you're right on this one, i didn't notice the difference

Answer (score 0):

You do need the RPLS530A from the second link you gave for your application -- the unit comes with wiring instructions, but in short, connect the wires labeled C and 2 to the power coming in from the line, and the wire labeled 1 to the wire going out to the load (provided you're replacing a single pole switch, i.e. one with two brass screws and one green screw -- if you're replacing a three-way switch, follow the instructions in the manual carefully, and comment here if you need more help).